# conditional column value with str_c?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have this DF and i need to create more columns, based on `vendas` (sales) on that platform, but i can't make it work, the best i did was to create the columns with value:

```
plataformas = c(dados0 %>% distinct(plataforma) %>% arrange(plataforma))$plataforma
dados0 <- map_dfc(plataformas, ~ dados0 %>% transmute(!! str_c("vendas.", .x) := 0)) %>% bind_cols(dados0, .)
```

but, if i try to use `ifelse`, i just can't. e.g. i have a game for PS3, i want vendas.PS3 to get the value of vendas, all the others vendas.x stay 0. any help? I also have the plataforma.x columns, but i can't get that `ifelse(str_c("plataforma.", plataforma), ...)` to work. sorry if i'm not being clear enough.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
dados = structure(list(nome = c("Tornado Outbreak", "Puzzle Chronicles", 
"Persona 4: Arena", "Jeopardy!", "Totally Spies! Totally Party"
), plataforma = c("Wii", "PSP", "PS3", "Wii", "Wii"), genero = c("Action", 
"Puzzle", "Fighting", "Misc", "Misc"), editora = c("Konami Digital Entertainment", 
"Konami Digital Entertainment", "Atlus", "THQ", "Ubisoft"), vendas = c(0.08, 
0.05, 0.45, 0.53, 0.1), lancamento = structure(c(NA, 14637, NA, 
NA, NA), class = "Date"), `avaliacao-criticos` = c(71, 62, 86, 
NA, NA), `numero-criticos` = c(7, 19, 47, NA, NA), `avaliacao-usuarios` = c(8.8, 
NA, 7.7, NA, NA), `numero-usuarios` = c(4, NA, 143, NA, NA), 
    fabricante = c("Loose Cannon Studios", "Konami", "Arc System Works", 
    NA, NA), plataforma.3DS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), plataforma.PS3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
    plataforma.PS4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.PSP = c(FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.PSV = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.Wii = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, TRUE), plataforma.WiiU = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE), plataforma.X360 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), plataforma.XOne = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you show the output that you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a new column which combine `"vendas."` with the `plataforma` value then pivot the data wide so that we have `vendas.[Platform]` and the values is from vendas column

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
dados = structure(list(nome = c("Tornado Outbreak", "Puzzle Chronicles", 
  "Persona 4: Arena", "Jeopardy!", "Totally Spies! Totally Party"
), plataforma = c("Wii", "PSP", "PS3", "Wii", "Wii"), genero = c("Action", 
  "Puzzle", "Fighting", "Misc", "Misc"), editora = c("Konami Digital Entertainment", 
    "Konami Digital Entertainment", "Atlus", "THQ", "Ubisoft"), vendas = c(0.08, 
      0.05, 0.45, 0.53, 0.1), lancamento = structure(c(NA, 14637, NA, 
        NA, NA), class = "Date"), `avaliacao-criticos` = c(71, 62, 86, 
          NA, NA), `numero-criticos` = c(7, 19, 47, NA, NA), `avaliacao-usuarios` = c(8.8, 
            NA, 7.7, NA, NA), `numero-usuarios` = c(4, NA, 143, NA, NA), 
  fabricante = c("Loose Cannon Studios", "Konami", "Arc System Works", 
    NA, NA), plataforma.3DS = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
    ), plataforma.PS3 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
  plataforma.PS4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.PSP = c(FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.PSV = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
      FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), plataforma.Wii = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
        TRUE, TRUE), plataforma.WiiU = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
          FALSE), plataforma.X360 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
          ), plataforma.XOne = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = c(NA, 
            -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyr)
dados_vendas <- dados %>% select(nome, plataforma, genero, editora, vendas) %>%
  mutate(column_name = paste0("vendas.", plataforma)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column_name, values_from = vendas, values_fill = 0)
```

Here is the results:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 7
  nome                         plataforma genero   editora                      vendas.Wii vendas.PSP vendas.PS3
  <chr>                        <chr>      <chr>    <chr>                             <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Tornado Outbreak             Wii        Action   Konami Digital Entertainment       0.08       0          0   
2 Puzzle Chronicles            PSP        Puzzle   Konami Digital Entertainment       0          0.05       0   
3 Persona 4: Arena             PS3        Fighting Atlus                              0          0          0.45
4 Jeopardy!                    Wii        Misc     THQ                                0.53       0          0   
5 Totally Spies! Totally Party Wii        Misc     Ubisoft                            0.1        0          0
```

Assume that each combination of `nome, plataforma, genero, editora` is unique - we can merge back the data by this command

```
final_data_set <- dados %>% 
  left_join(dados_vendas, 
            by = c("nome", "plataforma", "genero", "editora"))
```

Comment: i'm getting this error with the first code: `Can't convert <double> to <list>.`, can't see the issue

Comment: Then your actual datasets have multiple same `nome, plataforma, genero, editora` with different vendas. so when pivot some of them are only one value `double`, some of them are a list of `double`. Can you review and update your questions with those cases and what are you expecting to handle those cases?